# Flask static send from localhost to server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, docker-compose, localhost

I am deploying an application on localhost and listening on a port on a remote server which is bound to a domain, the application shows up fine on localhost and the static folder is not passed to the server, how can I solve this problem?
My code:

nginx.conf:

```
server {

    listen 3002;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass web:5000;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from flask_babel import Babel
# from flask.helpers import safe_join
import os
# from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _l
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config
from db_driver import DBDriver

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

# static = safe_join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # collect = Collect()
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return app


app = create_app()
babel = Babel(app)


@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(app.config["LANGUAGES"])
    # return 'uk'


@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error(error):
    return {"message": "Упс, помилочка 404!"}, 404


@app.route("/")
def index():
    staff_list = DBDriver.get_staff_list()
    return render_template("about.html", staff_list=staff_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Project structure:

|-app |-static
|-templates
|     |-app.py

|-nginx |-nginx.conf

|

|-docker-compose.yml

|

Comment: in english plz..

Comment: I have already changed